# как изменить цвет созданного окна cmd в bat

Tags: bat

Не знаю как изменить цвет созданного окна cmd в bat:

```
start "name" /D "D:\123" Start.bat
```

Где использовать `color`?

Comment: color https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/color

Comment: Да прямо в Start.bat можно было вставить

Answer (score 1):

Вызови сначала color, потом батник, вот так:

```
start "name" /D "D:\123" cmd /k "color e1 & start.bat"
```

Список доступных цветов (их 16) можно узнать через `color /?`